# Anyone have a source for pictures/screenshots/demos of Mud OLC systems?

Tags: design-patterns, mud

I really want to get access to some images of MUD (multi user domain/multi user dungeon) OLC (mud OnLine Creation), to use the structure of npcs/mobs/characters/areas/rooms that muds use on my own webgame project (http://www.ninjawars.net), which features a near predominant use of text itself.

I've played a mud for years, and experienced the OLC system of that mud first hand, but the mud went under, so I'm looking for

I tried compiling the type of Mud it was from source (ROM 2.4) but haven't been able to accomplish that.

I'm expecting that there are some images of the OLC of items/mobs/etc out there already, but I haven't been able to find any to base my implementation of the same concepts in my game off of.  If there's some live way to get access to a demo of OLC, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what use you'd find with screenshots! Ultimately it's just plain text, and you are going to be given a menu which is a list of whatever is changeable for that entity. You pick your option, enter a new value, repeat. There are 3 or 4 different brands of OLC for MUDs and although the presentation is slightly different for each, they're all pretty much the same really. (Here's a screenshot, though I don't think it'll do you much good: http://mud.wikia.com/wiki/NiMUD)

Are you actually interested in the OLC, or are you more interested in just learning what attributes exist on mobs, objects, rooms, etc? The latter can be more easily found by scanning the source code. (eg. Go through Merc.h in a ROM 2.4, for example.)

Comment: Well, the ideal would be to be able to get access to OLC so that I can play with it and get ideas directly from the actual thing itself.  I had a mud's OLC that I played on in the past, but I don't have any kind of access to it any more (it went down recently), so I lost that opportunity to see how those things were done right.  As I said, I didn't have any luck with an easy compile to create a running mud, so I came to gamedev to settle for screenshots or something else, 'cause I think I can still pull ideas from those.

Comment: Err, and yeah, going through the source (wasn't really sure where to look), if it's readable enough to piece back together into the ideas of what you got on an OLC screen, might work as well, I'll try that out as well, thanks.

Comment: I think I can work with Merc.h.  It's a bit dirtier than just viewing some OLC screen that shows everything at once directly, but I should be able to decipher it.